# Using certificate only on server side

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working on some WCF application. I already have client-side and server-side. Both communicates using WCF netTcpBinding or netNamedPipe. I want also a certificate only on server side, similar as it is with HTTPS. I've found very helpful guide here [click](https://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/wcf-security-cia-confidentiality-integrity-and-authentication-using-ssl-certificates/).

So according to this article, I'm interested in option 1 which is

> Option one provides (C + I) no authentication will happen for the client, In this case the TCP SSL (not the HTTPS SSL) will be used to provide the Confidentiality and Integrity, and the service will be configured like this below.

For now everything is clear for me, unfortunately later we can read:

> also you need to install the root certificate authority certificate for the service certificate on the client machine (typically in the Local Machine/Trusted Root Certification Authorities), and the service needs to have the below behaviour to specify the certificate for the service.

So here comes my question, is there any way to avoid changes on client machine? As mentioned earlier, I'm looking for a solution similar to WEB where the user is not obligated to install any kind of certificate on his machine.

Maybe I'm missing something, but maybe this rule applies only when I'm using a self-trusted/developer certificate? What if I will get certificate from a trusted company like Verisign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the certificate on the client-side simply to guarantee that the service on the server-side is trusted and that communication I secure. Just like visiting a website, we usually have a built-in certificate for the site before we browse the website, so the browser prompts the website is trusted. Unlike self-signed certificate, website certificates are issued by trusted third-party organizations to a specific host (web server), so all we need to do on the client-side is to install authoritative trusted third-party certificate before accessing the website. but we directly install the server-certificate on the client-side when we configure a self-signed certificate in the Local CA.
In fact, Browsers/OS already have some authoritative third-party certificate built-in. such as GlobalSign, VeriSign, so we just need to buy a certificate from them and configure them on the server-side, in which case, the client always trusts the server.
In addition to installing the server-side certificate, we may also need to configure the server-side identity on the client-side, which is usually the public key of the certificate, or the hostname. These configurations are generated automatically if we generate the client proxy and invoke the service by adding a service reference.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: So is there any way that my client will, for example, accept any server certificate? I'm aware that I can use a custom certificate validator on client side. Let's imagine it will return true for all certs, then I will be still obligated to add this cert manually on client side? In other words, I'm looking for solution where my connection will be encrypted using certificate without need to do anything on client side(adding to Local CA etc).

Comment: No. given that you absolutely trust the server certificate, the following code always returns true when validating the server certificate in the .Net framework project.    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
            {
                return true;
            };

Answer (score 1):

You don‘t need install somethings when you use an certificate issued by an trusted CA like GoDaddy and so on.